# ASP.Net DataGrid selectively bound entries

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have less knowledge of ASP.Net. Currently, I am using ASP.Net DataGrid control and mapped all the source information in UI successfully.

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = MyCollectionOfObjects
myDataGrid.DataKeyField = "MyKey"
myDataGrid.DataBind()
```

Now, the problem is, **I don't want all the objects to be mapped in the grid. Need to do some conditional filtering before mapping**. Is there any feature in DataGrid that allow me to decide bind or not bind some objects?

1) One option is mapping the collection(MyCollectionOfObjects) to a new collection that contains only the required objects by applying required filtering but I am not expecting that at this moment.

For example,

```
foreach(var item in MyCollectionOfObjects)
{
  if(item.InvalidEntry)
  {
     // This entry is not needed
  }
  else
  {
    // Okay with this entry
  }
}
```

Comment: You can most likely use LINQ to filter your collection before assigning your collection as datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Show/Hide a PlaceHolder based on the value of `InvalidEntry`.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("InvalidEntry")) %>' runat="server">

            <%# Eval("Column1") %>

        </asp:PlaceHolder>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

However, filtering the source data with Linq would be much easier.

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = MyCollectionOfObjects.Where(x => x.InvalidEntry == false);
```